# Replace a String with starting and ending with asterick ignore the parenthesis in present string

Tags: java, replace, case-insensitive

How do I get the required output?

input string :

```
 " software Company(1920 of 1897 ) IBM region(sb2). region(sb3)
```

word to be searched -

```
"software company(1920)"
```

Output

*software Company(1920)* IBM.IBM region(sb2). region(sb3)

In short I have to find a phrase and replace the same phrase with starting and ending asterisk (*), IGNORING THE CASE, and MATCH EXACT WORLD

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ignoring the parenthesis" and "match exact word". These two requirements seem contradictory.

Comment: What have you tried? This is usually the first question you will get on this site.

Comment: Another question: do you want an elegant answer or a low(er) level answer, manipulating the character arrays rather than using regex? I'd bet a dollar someone's going to put up some crazy answer with regex.

Comment: I think he needs to mark-up the text along with parentheses and regex might not allowing.. I too have faced the same situation.. still pending with me :(

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows :

```
    String str = "software Company (1920) IBM. software company (1920) TCS. SOftware Company (1920) HSBC. SOFTWARE COMPANY (1920) INFOSYS";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?i)(software company \\(1920\\))");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
    while(matcher.find()) {
        String curStr = matcher.group();
        str = str.replace(curStr,"*"+curStr+"*");
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `BackReference`

```
     String inputString = " software Company(1920) IBM. software company (1920)"+
           "TCS. SOftware Company (1920) HSBC. SOFTWARE COMPANY (1920) INFOSYS ";
     String patternStr = "([[a-zA-Z]{2}ftware Company\\([0-9]{4}\\)]{24})";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr );
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
     System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("*$1*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only got a couple of years of java experience, so someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't you use this: suppose your input string is `String input` and then use `input.indexOf([words to be searched])`. Once you have the indices you can simply use the `subString()` method, cut the total text into a bunch of little pieces, add in the asterisks, and then concatenate everything back together.

Answer (score 0):

use Regular Expression

for .net

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx

for java

http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CASE_INSENSITIVE` feature while compiling a pattern

```
String input = "Software company (1988)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("software company \\([1-9][0-9]{3}\\)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    if (matcher.matches())
    {
            System.out.println("*" + matcher.group(0) + "*");
    }
```

`group(0)` returns the entire matched pattern.